# Some doubts about action symmetry

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

We know that Symmetry of the Lagrangian ($\delta L = 0$) always yields some conservation law.

Now, if $\delta L \neq 0$, that doesn't mean we won't have conservation law, because if we can show action is invariant, we can still get what gets conserved.

Let's look at this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410864/366606), I don't get the following.

He mentions that we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}K + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{K} = \frac{dM}{dt}.
\end{equation}

To me, what $M$ represents to me is a total time derivative of some function $M$, so if we show that $L' = L + \frac{d}{dt}M$, we got action invariance and we will get something to be conserved.

1. The question is the author of the answer mentions that $M$ can be a function of $q, \dot q, t$ (note $\dot q$). I mean how can it be a function of $\dot q$?
2. In more detail: We know that action stays invariant if $L$ is changed by $\frac{d}{dt} M(q,t)$ when $M$ is a function of $q, t$, but if it's a function of $\dot q$, action won't stay invariant. Even in textbooks, I never saw such $M$ to be mentioned to be containing $\dot q$.  Even Landau says the following: [Check here](https://ibb.co/68dGLCr). Could you shed some lights?

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that the [linked answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410864/2451) at the end considers the example of [time-translation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451), where $K=\dot{q}$ and $M(q,\dot{q})=L(q,\dot{q})$ both do depend on $\dot{q}$.
2. OP's second question is a duplicate of e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112036/2451) Phys.SE post.